# getting LNK1104 error from a referenced project's .lib file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution with two projects: `myProject`, a DLL, and `myProject_Tester`, a Win32 console application that I'm using to debug the DLL.

When I build the solution, I get this error message in the Error List:

```
error LNK1104:
cannot open file 'U:\Software Development\c++ projects\myProject\Debug\myProject.lib'
U:\Software Development\c++ projects\myProject\myProject_Tester\LINK    
myProject_Tester
```

I added `myProject` as a reference in `myProject_Tester`, but when I'm editing `myProject_Tester.cpp`, and I try to enter `#include "myProjectDLL.h"` (the header file for `myProject`) to include the header file, `myProjectDLL.h` doesn't show up in the Intellisense.

I also added `U:\Software Development\c++ projects\myProject\Debug` under Additional Include Directories for `myProject_Tester`.

Is there somewhere else in the properties for `myProject_Tester` that I need to configure something to connect it with `myProject`?

EDIT:  Here is the header file I'm using for myProjectDLL.h:

```
//myProjectDLL.h

#ifdef MYPROJECT_EXPORTS
#define MYPROJECT_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define MYPROJECT_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

namespace myProject
{
    class FileOperator
    {
    public:
        static int openDoc(int projectID,int docID);
    };
}
```

Comment: Does "U:\Software Development\c++ projects\myProject\Debug\myProject.lib" exist?

Comment: No, but "U:\Software Development\c++ projects\myProject\Debug\myProject.dll" does.

Comment: Is this a .NET / CLR project?

Comment: No, it's not.  Strangely, I just rebuilt it and the error disappeared.  I still can't add the header file, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't set the Additional Include Directories setting correctly.  Your .h file surely isn't present in the Debug folder.  Make it U:\Software Development\c++ projects\myProject instead.

Do make sure the .lib file actually exists after building the "myProject" project.  If it is missing then you forgot to use __declspec(dllexport) to tell the linker to export the functions or classes that you want to make available.

And make sure that the projects are getting build in the correct order, "myProject" must be built *before* the console project starts building.  If necessary, right-click the console project in the Solution Explorer window, click "Project Dependencies" and tick myProject in the dialog box.

Comment: `U:\Software Development\c++ projects\myProject` is the solution directory; I get an error unless I use `U:\Software Development\c++ projects\myProject\myProject`, which is the project folder.  I edited my question to include the contents of my header file.  I'm using `__declspec(dllexport)` but it's not working.  `myProject` is already ticked in the "Project Dependencies" screen.

Comment: Also, I can't find the .lib file anywhere in my solution, even after building `myProject`.

Comment: It is **very** explicit in my answer. If you don't see a .lib getting generated then you forgot to export anything.  You did, you are not using MYPROJECT_API on the class declaration.

Comment: Ok, I changed the header so that the function is defined as: `static __declspec(dllexport) int openDoc(int projectID,int docID);`  This generates a library.  I was using `_API` because that is the instruction in [this MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx).