# "Error C1083: Cannot open include file" but I have a path to the include file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280686/getting-lnk1104-error-from-a-referenced-projects-lib-file), I have included a header file in the code for a console app that I'm using to test a DLL, but Visual Studio is returning the following error:

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'myProject.h': No such file or directory
```

But I have included the folder path for `myProject.h` in Additional Include Directories.  I also tried entering it under Configuration Properties->Debugging->Environment as a "PATH=<...>" value. The path is:  `U:\Software Development\c++ projects\myProject\myProject`, and when I go to that folder, I can see `myProject.h` in the folder.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "myProject.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << myProject::FileOperator::openDoc(1799,29);
}
```

When I type "#include", the Intellisense shows me just 3 items: the Debug folder corresponding to `U:\Software Development\c++ projects\myProject\myProject\Debug`,`stdafx.h`, and `targetver.h`.

Comment: Did you add your .h file manually to the project or from solution explorer?  You can right click on project , select "add new item" choose a "*header file" and then copy your code here. If you do this like that there should not be any problem

Comment: Sometimes you are running over a library that needs a reboot to get a path in the environmental variables

Answer (score 7):

Possible solution 1:

```
#include "../myProject.h"
```

Possible solution 2:

*Project Properties ~> C/C++ ~> General ~> Additional Include Directories*, try to set there path relative to the directory where is your `.sln` (solution) file. If the solution is in `U:\Software Development\c++ projects\myProject\` then try to set it to `$(SolutionDir)myProject`